# email verification via apppassword is not working

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my Django e-commerce project i was using my g mail account as EMAIL_HOST_USER for sending email verification for registering.but since may30 2022 the less secure apps feature has been disabled.and i got error when i tray to signup with new email .and to let 3rd party apps access gmail I generate an App password for my e-commerce in my gamil account and i change EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD from my gamil password to the new generated apppassword  and when i tray to signup,the error is gone but still it dose not send activation link to the new email !so how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: If you've enabled two-step verification, set a password for your app, then I think you need to shop around for SMTP alternatives.

Comment: @ttt bro is there any way to automate this process programmatically without physical action

Comment: You can use the [console](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#console-backend) or files for testing.